# How to loop an animation in Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like to loop an animation such that the final frame becomes the same as the initial frame. For instance, I would like to loop the following animation:

[image: Node Tree]

If repeat time rate of 45 frame, animation change direction each 45 frame. I change to 450 frame because my animation is total 450 frame. But repeat time does not work well.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Do you want to loop the noise falloff?

Comment: Yes, It's Noise Falloff. I want to make seamless when animation change from end frame to first frame. it's like endless loop animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Ping Pong* option of the *Repeat Time* node as follows.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: I really appreciate. I could make complete node. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ACE Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.